# As a Japanese passport holder in China can I renew my passport in China and still keep my Chinese visa?

Tags: visas, passports, china, japanese-citizens

I am a Japanese citizen in China. I want to renew my Japanese passport in China and still use the Chinese visa from my old passport.

Is this possible at the Japanese Embassy in China?

Comment: Do you actually have 2 questions? 1) Can I renew my Japanese passport in China and 2) If yes, will I still be able to use my Chinese visa that is in the old passport?

Comment: Just advise the embassy that you have a visa in the old passport and need to have it returned to you. This is a very common occurrence.

Comment: I believe this belongs on Expatriates.

Comment: @o.m. they could be a traveller as well, to be fair...

Answer (score 3):

If you renew your Japanese passport **and** are able to keep your old one, then yes, you can use your old and new passports together for travel to and from China.

This is stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=cn&SECTION=vi&SUBSECTION=ai&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C), a database used by airlines checking passengers.

> Valid visas or resident permits in expired passports are
>     accepted if holding a new valid passport of the same
>     nationality. The personal information on both passports must
>   be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You have to renew your passport and keep the old one is a common procedure. 
Then you have to travel with your two passports, the old one with the valid visa and the new one.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? Any more info than two short sentences?

Comment: I did it many times as a holder of a US visa i have to travel with my two passports.